# How to add an instagram, facebook and twitter logos in sharepoint modern communication site footer?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, communication-site

I am working on a new project where I am setting up communication as hubsite and bunch of team sites. I am looking to add a blue background colored footer to the landing page of the communication site.

There is a blog post: https://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2017/08/custom-modern-page-header-and-footer-using-sharepoint-framework-part-2/ using which I can add textual footer along with desired background color.

But as of my requirement, I have to add a footer like shown below. Also need to link these all logos to the respective social media account of the end client.
Is this possible to do, please help if someone has done anything like this.

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can bootstrap your project using this link https://github.com/thinkb4code/spfxFooter.

Comment: I would recommend to read the following documentation as well. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a reusable SPFx webpart which will allow you to add configurable header and footer via Webpart UI, you can find this solution [here](https://github.com/siddharth-vaghasia/SPFxWPConfigurableHeaderFooter). All you need to do.

I have tried and tested below html to footer

```
<div>
   <div class="ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white" style="height:40px;float: left;line-height:2.5;font-weight:bold;align-items: right;width: 100%;">
      <div style="float: right;padding-right: 135px;"> 
         <a href="https://twitter.com/batman" style="padding: 5px;">
         <img src="/sites/mysc/SiteAssets/twitter-16.png" alt="Smiley face"></a>
         <a href="https://facebook.com/batman" style="padding: 5px;">
         <img src="/sites/mysc/SiteAssets/facebook-3-16.png" alt="Smiley face"></a>
         <a href="https://instagram.com/batman" style="padding: 5px;">
         <img src="/sites/mysc/SiteAssets/instagram-16.png" alt="Smiley face"></a> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Please note that you have to upload you icons in SiteAssets library or refer from appropriate path.  Change the background color using in line style to 2nd level of div.

If you have your own SPFx extension like you tried above using blog, you have to add below code in onInit() method

```
public onInit(): Promise<void> {
  let bottomPlaceholder: PlaceholderContent = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(PlaceholderName.Bottom); 
          if (bottomPlaceholder) { 
            bottomPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = '<div>
   <div class="ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white" style="height:40px;float: left;line-height:2.5;font-weight:bold;align-items: right;width: 100%;">
      <div style="float: right;padding-right: 135px;"> 
         <a href="https://twitter.com/batman" style="padding: 5px;">
         <img src="/sites/mysc/SiteAssets/twitter-16.png" alt="Smiley face"></a>
         <a href="https://facebook.com/batman" style="padding: 5px;">
         <img src="/sites/mysc/SiteAssets/facebook-3-16.png" alt="Smiley face"></a>
         <a href="https://instagram.com/batman" style="padding: 5px;">
         <img src="/sites/mysc/SiteAssets/instagram-16.png" alt="Smiley face"></a> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>';

   return Promise.resolve();
 }
```

Note - change the path of images and hyperlink as per your requirement.

Screenshot on how it looks using above html

[image]

Icons Reference links

https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/white/twitter-16.png
https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/white/facebook-3-16.png
https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/white/instagram-16.png

If you want to use my resuable solution, below is what you can do

- Download code
- Modify solution to refer solution assets from cdn, azure etc(as per you requirement)
- Package the solution
- Upload to App catalog
- Install app to required site collection
- Create a modern page and add webpart
- Add required html to footer text area
- Click on register custom action, refresh the page and you are good to go
- To modify html, visit page again. you can update html in text area and click update custom action. Refresh the page.

Useful links -

[Basic understanding of SPFx Webpart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

[Deploy SPFx assets to Office 365 CDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/hosting-webpart-from-office-365-cdn)

Hope this helps...Happy coding..!!!
Please upvote and mark as answer if this helped.

Comment: Please mark it as answer it this worked..

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, I am going to try this out today, thanks for the valuable response.

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I attached the updated footer in the question description. Can you please advise how I can implement that as footer, I had to take off client logo, but where it says 'Client Logo', i have throw in a small image there. All links in the footer must be clickable.

Comment: Also, it would be very helpful if you could share steps to deploy your reusable SPFx solution that would be great as I am new to SPfx. In regards to configurable header and footer UI, is that something I can do post deployment of web part to the site?

Comment: @mdevm....regarding updated footer....please use html skills to create required footer..answer gives you basic understanding on how to move forward.

Comment: I already provided steps to use my reusable solution....if you are new to SPfx..please read https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

Comment: Thanks. So basically post deployment, I should be able to embed HTML in web part itself right?

Comment: yes....feel free to connect if you are stuck anywhere...you would be first person trying my solution :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94600/discussion-between-mdevm-and-siddharth-vaghasia).